# Need deep explanation for viewport /perspective/frustum calculations

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, webgl

I have a lot of tutorials & books, but I'm unable to understand how my viewport, my near & far distance etc are used to calc  perspective / frustum matrix.

I have the learningwebgl lessons, but.... I dont understand what viewport & 3D space adjustments are made....  What is my initial window projection size ? Why I see the triangle & square placed at z = -7.

Another thing I dont understand . A near plane of 0.001  creates the window projection just in front of my nose ? So what is my projection window dimension ?

I need a very deeper and basic help.... 
Can anybody help me ? Some really usefull links? I need graphical examples showing &  teaching how frustum is calculated.

Thanks

Comment: This should help: http://scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-advanced-lessons/perspective-and-orthographic-projection-matrix/

Comment: Thanks abstract ! I'm going to review it !

Answer (score 0):

There's this

http://games.greggman.com/game/webgl-3d-perspective/

Imagine you're in 2D. You have a canvas that's 200x100 pixels. If you draw at x = 201 it will be off the canvas. Similarly at x = -1 it will be off the canvas.

In WebGL it works in a 3D space that goes from -1 to +1 in x, y and z. The perspective / frustum matrix is the matrix that takes your 3d scene and converts it to this -1 / +1 space. The near and far values define what range in world space get converted to the -1 / +1 "clipspace". Anything outside that range will be clipped just like the 2D example. If you set near to 10 and far to 100 then something at Z = 9 will be clipped because it's too near and something at 101 will also be clipped as something that's too far. More specifically the near and far settings will form a matrix such that when a point is at Z = near it will become -1 when multiplied by the matrix and when it's at Z = far it will become +1 when multiplied by the matrix.

The viewport setting tells WebGL how to convert from the -1 to +1 space back into pixels.

Comment: Thanks g. I'm going to review your blog entries. They seem easy. Thanks again.